# Oracle query runs faster when I added some commented out lines

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query that runs slow (around 5 minutes), but if I add this commented out lines, it runs very fast (about 2 seconds), which doesn't make sense at all.
What could be the explanation ?

```
FROM .....
   --CREF.SYSTEM_PARAMETER sp,
     ...
WHERE     ....
   --t.LEDGER_EFFECTIVE_DATE BETWEEN NVL(adhoc.START_DATE, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - sp.value) and nvl(ec.END_DATE, TRUNC(SYSDATE))  -- use t.LEDGER_EFFECTIVE_DATE
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are any of the columns in the where clause indexed?

Comment: check the explain plan results to see if there is a difference

Comment: You're adding a join, but as part of that you're filtering data. What do the execution plans for the two queries show, and does it still not make sense when you compare them? Look at the indexes being used and the access paths in each plan.

Comment: The explain plan for both are exactly the same. There are indexes in the columns in the WHERE clause (I didn't check all of them, since it's a big WHERE clause), and the WHERE clause for both are exactly the same, except the fast result has the commented out line

Comment: The plans cannot be exactly the same - you're introducing another table when you uncomment that code.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I never uncomment out the code, rather I remove the commented out code. When I leave the commented out code in the query (it's in the query, but commented out), it runs fast (2 seconds). When I remove the commented out code from the query, the query runs slow (5 minutes)/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oracle creates a cache when the query is executed multiple times, which can result in reduced execution time. Are you executing the query multiple times?

Comment: I execute the one without the comment multiple times, and every time it runs slow (around 5 minutes). I also execute the one with the comment multiple times, and every time it runs fast (around 2 seconds)

Comment: Please check the execution plan. you must something missing here. Comment doesn't impact on execution time.

Comment: Right, I agree, it doesn't make sense to me, either. The explain plan for both are exactly the same.

Comment: can you share the query if this is not officially.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I am not sure if I can post the full query here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217496/discussion-between-nikhil-kulshrestha-and-faujong).

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the original query is cached with a poor execution plan, so every time the database sees that query it uses the cached plan. The amended version gets a fresh parse and a new execution plan.

Perhaps if you invalidated the slow version in some way (gather stats with `noinvalidate => false`, add an empty comment to the table, flush the shared pool, restart the database etc) it would get the new plan.

You mentioned *"The explain plan for both are exactly the same"* - the `explain plan` utility shows the plan likely to be used at the next execution. You need to check the actual runtime execution plan, not the explain plan.